# A question on locally compact metalindelöf spaces

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Is there a locally compact metalindelöf space $X$ with $|X|> 2^{\mathcal c}$, where $\mathcal c=2^\omega$?

Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure: any discrete space $X$ with $|X|>2^\mathfrak{c}$ is an example: it’s metrizable, so it’s actually paracompact.

Comment: Yes. I know this example. But is it metalindelof?

Comment: @Paul: Every paracompact space is metacompact, and every metacompact space is metaLindelöf: a locally finite open cover is point finite, and a point finite open cover is point countable.

Comment: O,O, Yes. I should beat my head on my desk! Thanks!

Comment: @Paul: You’re welcome! (I’ve had some of those temporary blind spots too; they’re really annoying. :-))